# Where is the mapGroupsWithState State stored? Docker and Local instance behaving differently

Tags: docker, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a project running Spark 2.2.1 Structured Streaming, with a calculation using mapGroupsWithState.

Running the project locally with

`spark-submit --class com.project.DataEnrichment --master local[4] target/scala-2.11/assembly-project.jar`
the local checkpointLocation contains the following folders:

```
- commits
- offsets
- sources
- state
```

But in our docker environment the checkpointLocation is missing the `state` folder. With the exact same application running.

I'm trying to figure out a way to keep the state outside of Docker so that it is possible to update the application without resetting the state, but first I have to locate it.

The docker environment is using the spark images from `gettyimages/spark:2.2.1-hadoop-2.7`

Is there any logical reason why the docker environment is not storing the State within the checkpoint Location? And is this configurable?

Comment: Are you setting the checkpointLocation option: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#recovering-from-failures-with-checkpointing? If you are, you can have it set to minio, hdfs, s3 or any other hdfs compatible file system